# Sass error on compilation NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass Use --trace for backtrace

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

Suddenly while working on a project, the following error came up.
How to resolve the below error that comes up while doing:

`sass --watch foundation.scss:../css/foundation.css --line-numbers`

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Sass compile was working till about a minute back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it was an issue with MY Sass code. I had some IE filters for gradient that was not coded properly. This is usually an issue with YOUR code and not with Sass or the compiler compiler or at some higher level with respect to ruby. Check your code for recent changes that might have some non-standard workarounds, especially for IE

Comment: Had the same issue, IE Filters where the problem. Thanks dude