# Sass was working fine for 6 months but not compiling anymore

Tags: compilation, sass

I have been using **SASS** for 6 months. This was working perfectly but now **SASS** will not compile.

- The version of SASS is: `3.2.14`
- The version of Compass is: `0.12.2`
- The version of Ruby is: `2.2.0`
- OS is: `Windows 8`

**Problem**:  SASS is not compiling.

Accessing the the path in Ruby, is no problem.  Ruby reads:

> "SASS is watching for changes. Press Crtl-C to stop."

I'm also using _partials and have imported them correctly to the `input.scss` file.

**Example Import**

`@import  '_footer', '_columns', '_content', '_h1-h6', '_mobile', '_home' ;`

I am also using Adobe Dreamweaver 5.5 as my text editor.

What I have tried in the effort to troubleshoot:

1. One by one, I have eliminated each partial from the @import to see if there was a coding problem.  This did not work!
2. Restarted Dreamweaver
3. Restarted PC
4. Uninstalled Ruby and re-installed Ruby

I also get the message in my command line:
[Sass] NoMethodError: undefined method `perform' for nil:NilClass

I'm not sure what else I can do, please help.

Comment: Did you try @import 'footer'? (without underscore), my sass imports don't have any of these, though the files do.

Comment: If you use "compile" instead of "watch", does it still not compile?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In my example Import, this is how it reads in Dreamweaver.  So yes, I did use the underscore with the _footer.  I just tried using compile and it returned as invalid option.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your question wrong.  No I didn't try it without the underscore because, I 'm using it as a partial file.

Answer (score 0):

Sass partials do not require the underscore when being imported. The underscore is required in the filename though, which tells the compiler to not create a separate CSS file corresponding to that partial. However, while importing you should just

`@import "footer", "columns";`

Reference: Look at how Sass based frontend framework foundation imports partials 
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation.scss

Even though the files are named with underscore like here (https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/master/scss/foundation/components)

Also, your error is most probably code related and not compiler related. Refer 
[Sass error on compilation NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass Use --trace for backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852946/sass-error-on-compilation-nomethoderror-undefined-method-count-for-nilnilcla/18852947#18852947)

I had the same problem and it was some non standard IE gradient filters I had copy pasted from some website. Let me know if that solves it for you

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I followed your direction and removed the underscore for my imports.  By the way, that was a good suggestion.  @import  'footer' , 'columns' , 'content' , 'h1-h6' , 'mobile' , 'home' ;  I also removed all the filters for IE.  I'm still getting the same message.  Is there another area I can eliminate, to isolate the problem?  Do I need to reboot, or restart Dreamweaver?

Comment: No this is not related to your dreamweaver. Can you try removing all but one of these partials for import now that you have your "_" removed in the import statements? Maybe you can zero in on which file is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks so very much for your help.  I found the problem and fixed it, working correctly now.

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted. If it was something else, kindly share the same in the answers