# NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform' for nil:nilClass

Tags: sass, compass-sass

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform' for nil:nilClass

The message above is what I'm getting from my command line.  This is after a type in my path and then the sass --watch input.scss:output.css then it returns the above error message.

- SASS version: 3.2.14
- Ruby version: 2.0.0 (The most recent version)
- Windows 8
- Using a localhost and a testing server.

I need help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852946/sass-error-on-compilation-nomethoderror-undefined-method-count-for-nilnilcla/18852947#18852947

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is "usually" a problem with your sass code and not with the compiler itself. Track back a few steps and see if you added any unusual code like IE filters etc.

You can refer here for more 
[Sass error on compilation NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass Use --trace for backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852946/sass-error-on-compilation-nomethoderror-undefined-method-count-for-nilnilcla/18852947#18852947)